# CSS позиционирование скроллбара

Tags: javascript, html, css

Мой дисплей и размер окна имеет ширину 1440 пикселей, но скроллбар забирает собой пару десяток пикселев, а тег body имеет ширину менее 1440 пикселей. Однако, когда скроллбар исчезает (появляется боковая панель в моем случае), ширина body возвращается 1440 пикселей. Как я могу сделать body на полной ширину? Или сделать скроллбар поверх body?

[image: Ширина обычная(скроллбар отжал место)]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так пусть скроллбар остаётся.

Answer (score 0):

Скроллбар, его внешний вид, цвет, ширина, высота и пр. полностью зависят от браузера. Следующие стили помогут вам изменить эти значения, но это не будет 100% работать у всех пользователей во всех браузерах.
Документация на скролл бар:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar

Итак, следующие стили помогут вам стилизовать ваш скролбар:

```
            :root {
                scrollbar-color: #7E6DF1 #fff;
                scrollbar-width: thin;
            }
            * {
                scrollbar-width: thin
            }

            ::-webkit-scrollbar {
                width: .3125rem;
                height: .3125rem
            }

            ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
                height: 3.125rem
            }

            ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
                background: #7E6DF1
            }

            ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
                background: #7E6DF1
            }

            ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
                background-color: #fff
            }
```

Однако этого недостаточно, чтобы сделать скроллбар "абсолютным", то есть чтобы он не занимал места на веб-странице. Чтобы body занял всю ширину страницы, вам необходимо убрать для него margin и указать overflow-y:

```
        html{
            overflow-y: overlay;
        }
        body{
            margin: 0;
        }
```

Это сделает ширину вашего body равной ширине экрана.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать `overflow-y: overlay;` для `body` чтобы он выходил за рамки скролбара и всегда имел 100% всей ширины экрана.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 101vh;
  overflow-y: overlay;
  background-color: gray;
}
```